# Mapping service and API

Tags: python, google-maps, mapping

I am building an application that will need to use a mapping service to locate a set of addresses, and include said map with its reporting features. Meaning that it would be beneficial if there was an easy way to convert the map into something printable.

I haven't started designing the application yet, but I will probably write it in Python. I am aware of [Google static maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), and it looks promising, especially the method of assigning waypoints (it is exactly what I need), but the map is limited to 640x640, so I was wondering if there are other options that would work well.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and create your own 640x640 tiles, then do some post-cleaning up before stitching them together.  Or, generate a kml file of the addresses and use another mapping service?

Comment: I have thought about stitching together individual tiles, yes. Thanks for mentioning KML, I hadn't heard of it before. Do you have any recommendations for alternative mapping services?

Comment: I had OpenStreetMap in mind - although I have not used it personally so did not want to recommend it. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page .  If you are at an early planning stage you could consider using Google Fusion Tables for generating a kml layer from addresses - has a very cool auto-geocode-from-address feature.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old, but the [MapQuest Static Maps Web Service](http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/) might be worth a look for anyone else who has a similar need.  The maximum dimensions of a static map request are 2048X2048, so a bit bigger than 640X640.  If you have any questions, check out the [forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums) on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com/).